# google bar charts animation

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am trying to animate this bar charts but it doesn't seems working.This bar chart represents real time data and update in every 2-3 seconds. I want to add easing so it visualize nicely. If anyone can help me out for fix the animation it would be great. Thanks

The chart looks like this ;
[Bar Chart](http://postimg.org/image/bvw86rmsl/)

```js
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html>
    <head>
        
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>MindStream Visual Chart</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      google.load("visualization", "1.1", {packages:["bar"]});

  
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
 
      function drawChart() {
         
   
        var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['EEG Power', 'High Gamma', 'Low Gamma', 'Theta', 'High Alpha', 'Low Alpha', 'Low Beta', 'High Beta','Delta'],
          ['Real Time Data', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        ]);


        var chart2 = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div2'));
  
  
          var bli;
          var att;
          var med;
          
          var highGamma;
          var lowGamma;
          var theta;
          var lowAlpha;
          var highAlpha;
          var lowBeta;
          var highBeta;
          var delta;
        
 
 // ajax 
        setInterval(function() {
          $.ajax({
             type        : 'get', 
             url         : 'jsonProvider', 
             data        : '',
             dataType    : 'json', 
             encode          : true
         }).done(function( data ) {
    
    console.log(data);
              //  console.log(data['eSense'].attention+"  "+data['eSense'].meditation+" "+data['eSense'].blinkStrength);
  
    att=data['eSense'].attention;
                med=data['eSense'].meditation;
                bli = data['eSense'].blinkStrength;
                highGamma = (data['eegPower'].highGamma != null) ? data['eegPower'].highGamma : 0 ;
    lowGamma = ( data['eegPower'].lowGamma != null) ?  data['eegPower'].lowGamma : 0 ;
    theta = (data['eegPower'].theta != null) ?  data['eegPower'].theta : 0 ;
    lowAlpha = (data['eegPower'].lowAlpha != null) ?  data['eegPower'].lowAlpha : 0 ;
    highAlpha = (data['eegPower'].highAlpha != null) ?  data['eegPower'].highAlpha : 0 ;
    lowBeta = (data['eegPower'].lowBeta != null) ?  data['eegPower'].lowBeta : 0 ;
    highBeta = (data['eegPower'].highBeta != null) ?  data['eegPower'].highBeta : 0 ;
    delta = (data['eegPower'].delta != null) ?  data['eegPower'].delta : 0 ;
    
    });
    

             
             
            data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['EEG Power', 'High Gamma', 'Low Gamma', 'Theta', 'High Alpha', 'Low Alpha', 'Low Beta', 'High Beta','Delta'],
            ['Real Time Data', highGamma, lowGamma, theta, highAlpha, lowAlpha, lowBeta, highBeta, delta]
          ]);
             
            var options2 = {
          chart: {
            title: 'EEG Power',
            subtitle: 'High Gamma, Low Gamma, Theta, High Alpha, Low Alpha, Low Beta, High Beta, Delta'}, 
      animation: {duration: 1000, easing: 'out'}
        };
            

        chart2.draw(data2, options2);
       
        });  

       
      
  
      }
    </script>
    
    
    
 </head>
    <body>
 

<table>
      <tr>
        <td class="container">
          <div id="chart_div2" style="width: 800px; height: 700px;float: left;"></div>      
        </td>
       
      </table>
           
      
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It will be easier for others to read and understand your codes if you fixed up the indentation.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `startup: true` to your options, so it would look like:

`animation: {duration: 1000, easing: 'out', startup:true}`